# str_replace stops when given string matched

Tags: php, string, replace

I need a function (`str_replace_dest` perhaps) similar to str_replace, but stop when a given string found.

```
$subject = "Hello World! Hello my friends.";
$search = "Hello";
$replace = "This is";
$destination = "!";

str_replace_dest($search, $replace, $subject, $destination);

//result

This is World! Hello my friends.
```

Does PHP have a built-in function like this? Or am I gonna need a hacky method?

Answer (score 3):

First way: use [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/substr_replace)

```
$subject = "Hello World! Hello my friends.";
$search  = "Hello";
$replace = "This is";
$destination = "!";

$result = substr_replace(
   $subject, 
   $replace, 
   strpos($subject, $search), 
   strlen($search)
);
```

Second way: use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) and pass limit explicitly:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\b'.preg_quote($search, '/').'\b/', $replace, $subject, 1);
```

First way is in general much faster, but it isn't applicable when you'll want, for example, do two or more replacements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do preg replace though:

```
$subject = "Hello World! Hello my friends.";
$search = "/Hello/";
$replace = "This is";
$destination = "!";

$subject = preg_replace($search, $replace, $subject, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use str_replace inside strstr, like this:

```
$subject = "Hello World! Hello my friends.";
$search  = "Hello";
$replace = "This is";
$destination = "!";
$subject = strstr(str_replace($search, $replace, $subject), $destination, TRUE);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass additional parameter COUNT to the str_replace function
edit, try:

```
$subject = "Hello World! Hello my friends.";
$search = "Hello";
$replace = "This is";
$destination = "!";

str_replace($search, $replace, $subject, 1);
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php Hope this helps. Here is talking about the count parameter to set the number of sequences.

Comment: No, it isn't a parameter to set number of replacements. It is a variable to capture how many replacements were done

Comment: Do you need to stop on a certain number of replacements or do you want to stop when reaching a certain part of the text? Something like :     Hello world, this is my world. Hello my world. to Hello xxx, this is my xxx. Hello my world. or Hello xxx, this is my world. Hello my world.